# return db.query to listeview (unless theres something better?)

Tags: android, sqlite, layout

I have in my DBAdapter, a getAll which should pull all the data from the database:

```
public Cursor getAllFinalscores()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE,
            KEY_FINALSCORE,
            KEY_HOLESPLAYED},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

and right now, I have it so that when a user wants to view all the data (from the main activity) it pulls it all as follows:

```
public void DisplayFinalscore(Cursor c)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "DATE: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "FINALSCORE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
            "HOLESPLAYED: " + c.getString(3),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.past_games:
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    DisplayFinalscore(c);
                }
                while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();

        }
    return true;
}
```

This works, however, it displays them all as little messages that pop up.  I am looking to display them in a list on a separate screen.

I created a new class (PastGames) which looks like the following:

```
public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_DATE};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter games = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, layout.pastgames_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(games);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

I also have my xml files:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_games"/>
```

and the row layout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Could help me with what I need to do in order to get that info into those layouts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a few things:

First, to access the Database, you should use a [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). It helps you read/write to it and create/update the Database.

Also, the `startManagingCursor()`-method is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. If you need to close your cursor, do it manually.

Don't open your Database-connection in the `onCreate`-method as it's only called when the Activity is first created. Use the `onStart`-method instead. Also, don't use the `onCreate`-method to populate the List. Create a new method for this and call it in the `onStart`-method, too. If the Activity gets backgrounded and foregrounded again, there won't be a problem with older data.

Also, if you have a `ListActivity`, you don't need a Layout containing a `ListView`. This is done automatically.

That's all I see for the moment. If you're getting any errors or exceptions, please post those messages, too. See if this gets you any further.

Comment: So I created a new onStart(Cursor c) in the PastGames activity, but I am still unclear on how to get that from the main activity.

Comment: You shouldn't create a `onStart(Cursor c)`-method. You should check out the [Activity-Lifecyrcle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: I think I understand what is going on now.  So right now I am pulling all the data from the database which is working correctly, and then running each line of that through a Toast.makeText...

I guess I am just trying to understand how to make that a list instead of a toast.

Comment: You get the Cursor from the Database-request and `ListAdapter` (a `SimpleCursorAdapter`) from it. To make your `ListActivity` show it, you use the `setListAdapter()`-method. [This is a nice example](https://github.com/LukasKnuth/NoteBook/blob/master/src/org/knuth/notebook/Main.java#L62) of how to do it.

Comment: my main activity only extends Activity though, not ListActivity.  I tried to switch and add new imports but it FC on open.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth startManagingCursor is deprecated in API 11 ... in lower API's version you dont have CursorLoader class so you can still use this method ... there no need to move code from onCreate to onStart ... SimpleCursorAdapter implemetiation do requery on Cursor when it's needed

Comment: @Selvin it shouldn't be used, that's why it's deprecated. It uses methods like the `requery()`-method, which sometimes cause problems. I found that it sometimes causes crashes even in Android 2.2 @Rob is the problem solved?

Comment: Not quite, though it may just be due to my overall lack of understanding on this programming language.  I have a friend looking at it with me now.  Your advice is helping us though.  Thank you